# Play ScalaWebSocket v2.5.* Upgrade to WebSocket required

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

I'm trying to create a websocket using Play ScalaWebsockets. I referred to their documentation which is located [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWebSockets). And as of the moment, I am using these SBT plugins which is required to use Play's websockets.

```
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.7",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.4.7" % "test",
```

This is my Actor:

```
 package actors.chat

 import akka.actor._
 import akka.stream._
 object ChatSocketActor {
    def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new ChatSocketActor(out))
 }

 class ChatSocketActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case msg: String =>
         out ! ("I received your message: " + msg)
   }
 }
```

In my Controller, I have this socket function:

```
 @Singleton
 class ChatController @Inject()(
    val messagesApi: MessagesApi,
    val pageMetaApi: PageMetaApi,
    implicit val materializer: Materializer,
    implicit val system: ActorSystem,
    implicit val wja: WebJarAssets
 ) extends Controller with I18nSupport with PageMetaSupport {

    import actors.chat.ChatSocketActor

    def index = Action { implicit request =>
       Ok(views.html.chat.index());
    }

    def socket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>
       ActorFlow.actorRef(out => ChatSocketActor.props(out))
    }

 }
```

After I compile and refresh the browser, I get this 426 response.

```
 Upgrade to WebSocket required
```

Is there something I missed?

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

I'm new to websockets. Problem was I was accessing the socket on a standard HTTP. I changed my routes to

```
# Chat
GET   /chat                       controllers.ChatController.index
GET   /websocket                  controllers.ChatController.socket
```

And a JS script in the /chat page which calls the websocket connection.

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:9000/websocket");
console.log(ws)
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the url from a websocket [client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

Comment: Yes I did. But it gives me an undefined error. And it disconnects. Also, I'm new to web sockets.

Comment: Can you tell us how you've solved the problem? Did you change the protocol in the URL, or?…